# How to configure cache for nodge eauth in Yii2

Tags: caching, yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components

Now, I use default cache for all:

```
'cache' => [
    'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
],
```

And I use nodge eauth for registration users.
Default config nodge:

```
'components' => [
  'eauth' => array(
    'class' => 'nodge\eauth\EAuth',
    'popup' => true, // Use the popup window instead of redirecting.
    'cache' => false, // Cache component name or false to disable cache. Defaults to 'cache' on production environments.
    'cacheExpire' => 0, // Cache lifetime. Defaults to 0 - means unlimited.
  )
]
```

What should I specify to `cache`?

Comment: Leave it false. If you dont wanna use cache.
Otherwise use 'cache' - component ID (in prod env this component is set to 'cache').

Comment: If my answer helps mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache requests, your config should be

```
'eauth' => [
            'class' => 'nodge\eauth\EAuth',
            'popup' => false, // Use the popup window instead of redirecting.
            'cache' => 'cache', // Cache component name or false to disable cache. Defaults to 'cache' on production environments.
            'cacheExpire' => 0, // Cache lifetime. Defaults to 0 - means unlimited.]
```

But I can be wrong.